# Call a function in Settings from spider Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I have two spiders `A` and `B`.
I need to call a function which is defined in the spider settings.py file

`Project Name
|--Project Name
|   |-- spiders
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- A.py
|   |   |-- B.py
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- items.py
|   |-- pipelines.py
|   |-- settings.py`

There is a function in settings.py, which I need to access from A.py and B.py on close of spider

settings.py

```
def revoke_ip():
    logging.info('Revoking access')
```

This is what I have tried from A.py:

```
def closed(self, reason):
    logging.info('Spider terminating because of %s' % reason)
    current_project_settings = get_project_settings()
    revoke_ip_call = getattr(current_project_settings, "revoke_ip")
    revoke_ip_call()
```

But this thing doesn't work nor does what is mentioned [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scrapy-users/LrXYwy-0qRE)

Is there anything that I am doing wrong or any other way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When importing a file, Python only searches the current directory, the directory that the entry-point script is running from, and sys.path which includes locations such as the package installation directory. You can import the settings file to call the function. To do this, add this to your function:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '../')
import settings
```

Comment: And how do I call the revoke function, settings.revoke()?
If I run the crawler from the outer `project name` folder as `scrapy crawl A`, I get an error `ImportError: No module named settings`

Comment: This thing partially solved my problem, so I am upvoting the answer. Thanks!

Comment: If you run your project from other folder, you must specify what folder contains the module you wanna use. You can try using an absolute path to the settings module. You're welcome, i hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me, thanks to the answer that @Jose posted, was that as `settings.py` was in a different directory than the spider which I was running and Python only searches the current directory.

So I tried checking the path of the file that it gives every-time I run the spider and apparently the path that I get was

```
/tmp/unpacked-eggs/__main__.egg/project name/spiders
```

So, what I had to do was:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + '/../')
import settings
```