# scrapy: call a function when a spider opens

Tags: python, scrapy

I have found plenty of information on calling a function when a Scrapy spider quits (viz: [Call a function in Settings from spider Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40418046/call-a-function-in-settings-from-spider-scrapy)) but I'm looking for how to call a function -- just once -- when the spider opens. Cannot find this in the Scrapy documentation.

I've got a project of multiple spiders that scrape event information and post them to different Google Calendars. The event information is updated often, so before the spider runs, I need to clear out the existing Google Calendar information in order to refresh it entirely. I've got a working function that accomplishes this when passed a calendar ID. Each spider posts to a different Google Calendar, so I need to be able to pass the calendar ID from within the spider to the function that clears the calendar.

I've defined a base spider in init.py that looks like this:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
## import other stuff I need for the clear_calendar() function

class BaseSpider(CrawlSpider):

    def clear_calendar(self, CalId):

        ## working code to clear the calendar
```

Now I can call that function from within parse_item like:

```
from myproject import BaseSpider

class ExampleSpider(BaseSpider):

    def parse_item(self, response):

       calendarID = 'MycalendarID'
       self.clear_calendar(MycalendarID)

       ## other stuff to do
```

And of course that calls the function every single time an item is scraped, which is ridiculous. But if I move the function call outside of def parse_item, I get the error "self is not defined", or, if I remove "self", "clear_calendar is not defined."

**How can I call a function that requires an argument just once from within a Scrapy spider? Or, is there a better way to go about this?**

Comment: Off the top of my head... I think you need to declare a `spider_opened` method...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is totally a better way, with the [`spider_opened`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html?highlight=opened_spider#spider-opened) signal.

I think on newer versions of `scrapy`, there is a `spider_opened` method ready for you to use inside the spider:

```
class MySpider(Spider):
    ...        
    calendar_id = 'something'

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
        spider = super(MySpider, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
        crawler.signals.connect(spider.spider_opened, signal=signals.spider_opened)
        return spider

    def spider_opened(self):
        calendar_id = self.calendar_id
        # use my calendar_id
```

Comment: Excellent - I have also looked into this, but I don't know how to get the calendarID passed in there. Can I just reference myspidername.calendarID, assuming calendarID is defined in the individual spider class?

Comment: yes, you can even pass it as an argument when running `scrapy crawl myspider calendar_id=something` and use it directly as a spider argument on your entire spider. I am updating the code

Comment: @NFB also looks like the `spider_opened` method is not implemented by default, so you'll have to connect the signal into the spider, I am updating my answer.

Comment: Just so I am clear, this code still should be in the base spider class from which the many other classes are defined, correct?

Comment: yeah, no problem with that, just remember to change the name of the spider (`MySpider` on my example) to the one you have (`BaseSpider` I assume), check that line inside `from_crawler` also uses the spider name inside `super`

Comment: Done, and this is the solution I was looking for. Thanks for your help. Marked answered.